# Ограничение выбора radio по сумме значений

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть **форма**, в ней несколько полей, в них радио-кнопки со значением от **0 и выше**, а так же кнопка отправить - которая не активна.
Нужно ограничить выбор (я так понимаю с помощью JavaScript или jQuery) десятью балами. То есть, чтобы пользователь мог распределить **10 балов** между полями выбора и при достижении в **10 балов** (суммарно) - кнопка "отправить" становилась активной. **А главное**, чтобы б**ольше 10 балов** выбрать было **нельзя.**

Код на CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/zikwal/pen/RwGmQZL

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Тест</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style media="screen">
    .form_radio_btn {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 10px;
}
.form_radio_btn input[type=radio] {
display: none;
}
.form_radio_btn label {
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 0px 15px;
line-height: 34px;
border: 1px solid #999;
border-radius: 6px;
user-select: none;
}

/* Checked */
.form_radio_btn input[type=radio]:checked + label {
background: #ffe0a6;
}

/* Hover */
.form_radio_btn label:hover {
color: #666;
}
.button {
  margin: 20px;
}
    </style>
    <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
      <h1>Распределите 10 балов среди утверждений</h1>
      <div class="quest-1">
  <h2>1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-0_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="0" checked>
    <label for="radio-0_1">0</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-1_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="1">
    <label for="radio-1_1">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-2_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="2">
    <label for="radio-2_1">2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-3_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="3">
    <label for="radio-3_1">3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-4_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="4">
    <label for="radio-4_1">4</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-5_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="5">
    <label for="radio-5_1">5</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-6_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="6">
    <label for="radio-6_1">6</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-7_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="7">
    <label for="radio-7_1">7</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-8_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="8">
    <label for="radio-8_1">8</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-9_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="9">
    <label for="radio-9_1">9</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-10_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="10">
    <label for="radio-10_1">10</label>
  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="quest-2">
  <h2>2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-0_2" type="radio" name="radio-2" value="0" checked>
    <label for="radio-0_2">0</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-1_2" type="radio" name="radio-2" value="1">
    <label for="radio-1_2">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-2_2" type="radio" name="radio-2" value="2">
    <label for="radio-2_2">2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-3_2" type="radio" name="radio-2" value="3">
    <label for="radio-3_2">3</label>
  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="quest-3">
  <h2>3 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-0_3" type="radio" name="radio-3" value="0" checked>
    <label for="radio-0_3">0</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-1_3" type="radio" name="radio-3" value="1">
    <label for="radio-1_3">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-2_3" type="radio" name="radio-3" value="2">
    <label for="radio-2_3">2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-3_3" type="radio" name="radio-3" value="3">
    <label for="radio-3_3">3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-4_3" type="radio" name="radio-3" value="4">
    <label for="radio-4_3">4</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-5_3" type="radio" name="radio-3" value="5">
    <label for="radio-5_3">5</label>
  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="quest-4">
  <h2>4 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-0_4" type="radio" name="radio-4" value="0" checked>
    <label for="radio-0_4">0</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-1_4" type="radio" name="radio-4" value="1">
    <label for="radio-1_4">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-2_4" type="radio" name="radio-4" value="2">
    <label for="radio-2_4">2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-3_4" type="radio" name="radio-4" value="3">
    <label for="radio-3_4">3</label>
  </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="button" name="button" disabled>Отправить</button>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Добавил ответ. Думаю он подойдёт))

Comment: @Алексей-Шиманский спасибо большое! Именно то, что нужно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно ещё надо допилить напильником, но задел таков:

```js
const Selector = {
    quest: '.quest',
    radioButton: 'input[type=radio]',
    checkedRadio: 'input[type=radio]:checked',    
    label: '.form_radio_btn label',
};

$(Selector.radioButton).on('click', function() {    
    let sum = 0;
    let maxSum = 10;
    let clickedVal = +$(this).val();
    $('button[type=submit]').prop("disabled", true);

    $(Selector.checkedRadio).each(function(index, element) {
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });

    if (sum <= maxSum) {
        let $questWrapper = $(Selector.quest);
        
        $questWrapper.find(Selector.label).removeClass('disable-btn');
        $questWrapper.each(function(index, element) {
            let $label = $(this).find(Selector.label);
            let checkedVal = $(this).find(Selector.checkedRadio).val();

            $label.each(function(index, element) {
                let currentVal = +$(this).text();
                
                if (currentVal > checkedVal && sum - checkedVal + currentVal > maxSum)
                    $(this).addClass('disable-btn');                
            });
      });
    }

    if (sum === maxSum) {
        $('button[type=submit]').prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 11px;
}

.disable-btn {
  pointer-events: none;
  background: grey;
}


/*--------------------------*/

.form_radio_btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.form_radio_btn input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.form_radio_btn label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  line-height: 34px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 6px;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Checked */

.form_radio_btn input[type=radio]:checked+label {
  background: #ffe0a6;
}


/* Hover */

.form_radio_btn label:hover {
  color: #666;
}

.button {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Тест</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
    <h1>Распределите 10 балов среди утверждений</h1>
    <div class="quest-1 quest">
      <h2>1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-0_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="0" checked>
        <label for="radio-0_1">0</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-1_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="1">
        <label for="radio-1_1">1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-2_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="2">
        <label for="radio-2_1">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-3_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="3">
        <label for="radio-3_1">3</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-4_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="4">
        <label for="radio-4_1">4</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-5_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="5">
        <label for="radio-5_1">5</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-6_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="6">
        <label for="radio-6_1">6</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-7_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="7">
        <label for="radio-7_1">7</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-8_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="8">
        <label for="radio-8_1">8</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-9_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="9">
        <label for="radio-9_1">9</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-10_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="10">
        <label for="radio-10_1">10</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="quest-2 quest">
      <h2>2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-0_2" type="radio" name="radio-2" value="0" checked>
        <label for="radio-0_2">0</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-1_2" type="radio" name="radio-2" value="1">
        <label for="radio-1_2">1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-2_2" type="radio" name="radio-2" value="2">
        <label for="radio-2_2">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-3_2" type="radio" name="radio-2" value="3">
        <label for="radio-3_2">3</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="quest-3 quest">
      <h2>3 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-0_3" type="radio" name="radio-3" value="0" checked>
        <label for="radio-0_3">0</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-1_3" type="radio" name="radio-3" value="1">
        <label for="radio-1_3">1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-2_3" type="radio" name="radio-3" value="2">
        <label for="radio-2_3">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-3_3" type="radio" name="radio-3" value="3">
        <label for="radio-3_3">3</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-4_3" type="radio" name="radio-3" value="4">
        <label for="radio-4_3">4</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-5_3" type="radio" name="radio-3" value="5">
        <label for="radio-5_3">5</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="quest-4 quest">
      <h2>4 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-0_4" type="radio" name="radio-4" value="0" checked>
        <label for="radio-0_4">0</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-1_4" type="radio" name="radio-4" value="1">
        <label for="radio-1_4">1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-2_4" type="radio" name="radio-4" value="2">
        <label for="radio-2_4">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form_radio_btn">
        <input id="radio-3_4" type="radio" name="radio-4" value="3">
        <label for="radio-3_4">3</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="button" name="button" disabled>Отправить</button>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

раз уж написал, пусть останется.
без раскраски нективных радио-кнопок.

```js
let $btns = $(".form_radio_btn input");

$btns.click(function(){
  let values = $btns.filter(":checked")                  
                  .get()
                  .map(v => +v.value );
                  
  let sum = values.reduce((acc,v) => acc + v, 0);
  let l = values.length;
                  
  if(sum > 10){
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
    sum -= $(this).val();
    l--;
  }
                  
  let allow = sum <= 10 && l == 4;
  $("[type=submit]").prop('disabled', allow ? '' : 'disabled');
});
```

```css
.form_radio_btn {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 10px;
}
.form_radio_btn input[type=radio] {
display: none;
}
.form_radio_btn label {
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 0px 15px;
line-height: 34px;
border: 1px solid #999;
border-radius: 6px;
user-select: none;
}

/* Checked */
.form_radio_btn input[type=radio]:checked + label {
background: #ffe0a6;
}

/* Hover */
.form_radio_btn label:hover {
color: #666;
}
.button {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
      <h1>Распределите 10 балов среди утверждений</h1>
      <div class="quest-1">
  <h2>1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-0_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="0" checked>
    <label for="radio-0_1">0</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-1_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="1">
    <label for="radio-1_1">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-2_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="2">
    <label for="radio-2_1">2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-3_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="3">
    <label for="radio-3_1">3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-4_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="4">
    <label for="radio-4_1">4</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-5_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="5">
    <label for="radio-5_1">5</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-6_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="6">
    <label for="radio-6_1">6</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-7_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="7">
    <label for="radio-7_1">7</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-8_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="8">
    <label for="radio-8_1">8</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-9_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="9">
    <label for="radio-9_1">9</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-10_1" type="radio" name="radio-1" value="10">
    <label for="radio-10_1">10</label>
  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="quest-2">
  <h2>2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-0_2" type="radio" name="radio-2" value="0" checked>
    <label for="radio-0_2">0</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-1_2" type="radio" name="radio-2" value="1">
    <label for="radio-1_2">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-2_2" type="radio" name="radio-2" value="2">
    <label for="radio-2_2">2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-3_2" type="radio" name="radio-2" value="3">
    <label for="radio-3_2">3</label>
  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="quest-3">
  <h2>3 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-0_3" type="radio" name="radio-3" value="0" checked>
    <label for="radio-0_3">0</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-1_3" type="radio" name="radio-3" value="1">
    <label for="radio-1_3">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-2_3" type="radio" name="radio-3" value="2">
    <label for="radio-2_3">2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-3_3" type="radio" name="radio-3" value="3">
    <label for="radio-3_3">3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-4_3" type="radio" name="radio-3" value="4">
    <label for="radio-4_3">4</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-5_3" type="radio" name="radio-3" value="5">
    <label for="radio-5_3">5</label>
  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="quest-4">
  <h2>4 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-0_4" type="radio" name="radio-4" value="0" checked>
    <label for="radio-0_4">0</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-1_4" type="radio" name="radio-4" value="1">
    <label for="radio-1_4">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-2_4" type="radio" name="radio-4" value="2">
    <label for="radio-2_4">2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form_radio_btn">
    <input id="radio-3_4" type="radio" name="radio-4" value="3">
    <label for="radio-3_4">3</label>
  </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="button" name="button" >Отправить</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но Ваш код, все же, оставляет возможность выбрать большее число! (Хоть и не показывает это визуально - кнопка отключается при большем выборе) В любом случае, может кому-то понадобиться именно Ваше решение!

Спасибо Вам большое!